# Check correctly status notification Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have Code:

```
static public function alerts() {
    $user = Auth::user();
    $alerts = [];
    foreach ($user->unreadNotifications as $notification) {
        switch($notification->type) {
            case 'App\Notifications\OrderTracker':
                $alerts['order'] = $notification->type;
            break;
            case 'App\Notifications\ReviewTracker':
                $alerts['review'] = $notification->type;
            break;
        }
            $alerts['all'] = $notification->type;
    }

    return ($user->unreadNotifications) ? $alerts : null;
}
```

In blade I want wirte count notifications by type:

```
Orders {{ count(Helper::alerts()['orders']) }}
Reviews {{ count(Helper::alerts()['reviews']) }}
All {{ count(Helper::alerts()['all']) }}
```

I think, that this crutch and not correctly. How I can check notification type easy?

Comment: You're overwriting the same value with `$alerts['order'] =`. Do you want to count notifications by type?

Comment: I don't understand the purpose or use of this code at all. Are you using some sort of library that deals with notifications or is this part of a greater piece of code you've written?

Comment: I want write in array count notifications by type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this instead. This code will create just one query to DB. Also, if you'll add more notification types, this code will be easier to maintain.

```
static public function alerts() {
    $types = [
        'order' => 'App\Notifications\OrderTracker',
        'review' => 'App\Notifications\ReviewTracker'
    ];
    foreach ($types as $key => $type) {
        $alerts[$key] = auth()->user()->unreadNotifications->where('type', $type)->count();
    }
    return $alerts['all'] = array_sum($alerts) ? $alerts : null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is good. But how I can write alerts > 0 ? Your code get zero alerts.

Comment: If `array_sum($alerts)` will return `0`, the `alerts()` method will return `null`.

Answer (score 0):

He wants something simple as this

```
static public function alerts() {
  $user = Auth::user();
  $alerts = [
    'orders'=>0,
    'review'=>0,
    'all'=>0
  ];

 foreach ($user->unreadNotifications as $notification) {
    switch($notification->type) {
        case 'App\Notifications\OrderTracker':
            $alerts['order'] +=1; 
        break;
        case 'App\Notifications\ReviewTracker':
            $alerts['review'] +=1;
        break;
    }
        $alerts['all']+=1;
 }

    return ($user->unreadNotifications) ? $alerts : null;
}
```